# Q: Unable to return a list of events base on the categories?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Unable to return a list of events base on its categories, the eventsData is unable to get the category type which contains the categoryId. The error occurs when the getter 'categories' isn't defined for the type 'Events' any idea what this means?

Code:

```
//ListView
final routeArgs =
        ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
    final categoryId = routeArgs['id'];

    List<Events> displayedEvent;
    final eventsData = Provider.of<Events>(context);

    displayedEvent = Events.where((event) {
      return eventsData.categories.contains(categoryId);
    }).toList();

    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
        return EventItem(
          id: displayedEvent[index].id,
          title: displayedEvent[index].title,
        );
      },
      itemCount: displayedEvent.length,
    );
```

Data file:

```
class Events with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Event> _items = [
    Event(
      id: '101',
      categories: [
        'c1',
        'c3',
      ],
      title: 'Food Festival',
    ),
    Event(
      id: '102',
      categories: [
        'c1',
        'c4',
      ],
      title: 'Fireworks Festival',
    ),
  ];

  List<Event> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  Event findById(String id) {
    return _items.firstWhere((event) => event.id == id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this 
```
eventsData.categories.
        .where((element) => element.categoryId== categoryId )
        .toList();
```

Comment: @ShahryarRafique it worked after i changed it to 
`eventsData.items.where((event) => event.categories.contains(categoryId)).toList();`